# How xml-node-type = 'hidden' play a role in a loop

Tags: xml, openedge, progress-4gl

I am writing progress 4GL code that builds an XML address tag based on multiple qualifiers like supplier, buyer, issuer of invoice, and delivery party using one temp-table tt_address.

for every address, we have streets 1,2 & 3. I want to show them in the XML if available else hide the tags.

Below is my code.

```
do i = 1 to num-entries(qualifiers):
create tt_address.
if ad_line1 <> ""
buffer tt_address:buffer-field("tt_address_street1"):xml-node-name = "STREET_1".
tt_address_street1   = trim(ad_line1).
else
buffer tt_address:buffer-field("tt_address_street1"):xml-node-type = "hidden".
if ad_line2 <> ""
buffer tt_address:buffer-field("tt_address_street2"):xml-node-name = "STREET_2".
tt_address_street2   = trim(ad_line2).
else
buffer tt_address:buffer-field("tt_address_street2"):xml-node-type = "hidden".
if ad_line3 <> ""
buffer tt_address:buffer-field("tt_address_street3"):xml-node-name = "STREET_3".
tt_address_street3   = trim(ad_line3).
else
buffer tt_address:buffer-field("tt_address_street3"):xml-node-type = "hidden".
end.
```

**Problem:-** In the above case if the first loop passes the condition like ad_line1 <> '' and ad_line2 & ad_line3 = '' then it returns below
<STREE_1>'ADDRESS1XXXXX'</STREET_1>

In the second loop (i.e., for other qualifier) if I have ad_line1 <> '' and ad_line2 = '' & ad_line3 <> '' then it is still giving ad_line1 only as below
<STREE_1>'ADDRESS2XXXXX'</STREET_1>

Please let me know, how to overcome from this by not using separate temp-table for each address tag.

Hope it clarifies!!!

**My analysis:-** Because of first iteration making the tt_address_street2 & tt_address_street3 as "hidden" it  is giving the next iterations as hidden only even though they have the information.

**Actions I did:-** For each loop starting I am making the node-type to "element" for all the tt_address_street tags as below
buffer tt_address:buffer-field("tt_address_street2"):xml-node-type = "element".
also observed that it is assigning the value for tt_address_street2, but in the XML generation, I couldn't see the value except <STREET_1> information.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your requirement correctly, this won't be possible using the xml-node-type attribute. The attribute is set on the buffer level, not on the record level. It applies at the time of calling WRITE-XML on the temp-table or ProDataset equally to all records in that table.

If your requirement is to skip the empty xml-elements from the output, did you try to use the last optional parameter ob WRITE-XML - the omit-initial-values

When that's set to TRUE, those character fields with empty values won't be written to the XML document, when that matches the intial value.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response Mike Fechner, Actually the attribute is adding at record level only for a particular buffer. Also, I tried using the last parameter set to true as below                      QAD_message_header:write-xml("FILE", 
                               lv_file,
                               true,
                               ?,
                               ?,
                               false,
                               FALSE,
                               FALSE,
                               true).        But still I am failed.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the empty data written on a pre-record basis, you could look at the *omit-initial-values* argument to [WRITE-XML()](https://docs.progress.com/bundle/openedge-abl-reference-122/page/WRITE-XML-method.html?labelkey=product_openedge_122) .